# swap internal sd card to external storage

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, insufficient-memory

I wanna make my external sd my internal one without having the need to use an app. So Instead of having 8GB of internal storage I want to have 64GB (taken from the micro sd card). It worked on my previous phone Gt-i8530 if I changed the `vold` file to this:

```
# internal sdcard
{
ums_sys_path = /sys/class/android_usb/f_mass_storage/lun0/file
secure_format = enable
discard = enable
}
dev_mount sdcard1 /storage/extSdCard 8 /devices/sdi2/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0 encryptable_nonremovable

# external sdcard
{
ums_sys_path = /sys/class/android_usb/f_mass_storage/lun1/file
supported_exfat = disable
android_secure_containers = enable
}
dev_mount sdcard /storage/sdcard0 auto /devices/sdi0/mmc_host/mmc1/mmc1
```

So now I want to do that same thing on my new phone SM-G3858. But I only have in `vold`:

```
#storage_struct = series, "/mnt/sdcard/extStorages"
#storage_struct = parallel
{
supported_exfat = yes
}
dev_mount sdcard /storage/extSdCard auto /devices/platform/sdhci-pxav3.0/mmc_host/mmc1
```

Now what do I need to change or add here to swap it as on the previous phone? I´m a bit confused that a) it right away says extsdcard here and b) that there is only one command line instead of 2 . I guess the reason is the `#storage` structure?

And suggestions please?

Comment: Just for clarification on the pending edit: you want to swap the partitions (i.e. make them changing their roles, so it seems you've got 64GB internal storage and a 8GB sd card) – or to "virtuall merge" them (so they appear as a single storage, and there's no longer an external SD card)? I assume the former, but the editor seems to think the latter.

Comment: Please make it clear. Do you want to swap your memory card with the whole _/data_ partition or just with the Internal Storage (_/storage/sdcard0_ or _/storage/sdcard_) ? I think doing the latter one is utterly meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's important to you that the storage volumes are swapped, in Android Marshmallow the sd-card storage can be added to your internal storage with Adaptable storage.

Adaptable storage "enables a user to set up his SD card as internal storage, and store applications, their data, and media on an adopted SD card." –[Source](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/109134/p/1449,9582)

Note: A high-speed card (UHS-1) is highly recommended, since you'll be experiencing lag and slow application speed with slower/older cards.

To use the feature:

1. Turn off your phone
2. Insert the SD-card
3. Turn on your phone
4. Choose "use sd-card as Internal Storage" (When provided with the option - it should appear as a notification)

Android will then set up the card for internal use.
This will make Android show your sd-card as part of the internal storage and be used as such. The proces also encrypts the card, so your data is safe.

Note: When the card is set up as internal storage, you won't be able to use the card as a normal sd-card, fx. plugging it out and into your computer to copy files won't work. To use the sd-card like this again at a later point, you'll have to reformat the card.

Comment: Is it possible to do it to an already used SD card? One that already has a lot of apps in it.

Comment: No, the card will be re-formatted so it only works with the device. Basically it won't function as a normal sd-card anymore (unless you re-format it again for that), but as part of the internal storage. However as part of the internal storage, apps will be installed to it by Android automatically when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Most new devices dont have partition of sdcard that means instead of having internal memory and that called usb storage app only internal is present...they dont separate it and only create a system space. If you check your apps list in settings Downloaded apps and all apps list are all in internal and no option for moving to sd...This mostly happen on android kitkat devices...

Answer (score 0):

It depends what phone you are using and what version of Android you are using. If you are using Android Marshmallow there is something called Adoptable storage which can be turned on in settings. Most phones have this option so looking online for this shouldn't be difficult.

If however you are using one of the few phones that does not allow adoptable storage like Samsung S7 family or LG G5 than you need to go through these alternative steps.

--THIS WILL FORMAT YOUR SD CARD, BACKUP YOUR DATA!!!

1) have adb installed. You can get a slim version from XDA http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790

2) run:

$> adb shell
$> sm list-disks adoptable disk

this will give you a result like: 179,64

then run this command. the last number is the % of the storage you want as EXTERNAL, not adoptable. So, let's say you want 60% of the SD card as adoptable storage, you should run

$> sm partition disk:179,64 mixed 40

type the number you got before after disk: Also, if you get some permission errors, type su  and then try the command again

3) reboot your phone.

Done. Check the storage on your device and you should see a part of the sd card on the internal storage and the other on the external

If you end up getting a "corrupted" error on your SD card portion of device storage here is how you fix it.

After you have partitioned the disk and while your SD card is corruped enter In the terminal the following:
$> adb shell sm list-volumes all

Which will list your volumes, for example:
    private mounted null
    public:179,1 mounted B5B1-140C
    private:179,3 unmountable null
    emulated mounted null

Then enter the following replacing 179,3 with whichever disk numbers you are given:
$> adb shell sm format private:179,3
$> adb shell sm mount private:179,3

Now your SD card in device storage should be properly mounted and your portable storage will still be there.

This worked on my LG G5 and should work on the S7.